# Is it possible to evaluate a matlab function block in simulink only if a certain input changes?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a matlab function block in simulink, but I want this block to operate only if the first (of two) input changes. When the second input changes without a change of the first input, the block must remain it's value. How can i implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a "Memory" block and a comparison or a "Detect Change" block to detect the changes in your signal. Use an "Enabled Subsystem" and put your matlab function into it to have the possibility to disable it. Make sure you set the "Output when disabled" parameter of your output ports to the intended behaviour.

Comment: So i need to connect my first input to the detect change block and then I have I have to connect this to the enable control input port of the subsystem?

Comment: Yes, exactly that way.